# How to add string values with error bars in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, errorbar

I want to create an error bar graph

like this where for example for Masi Minimum error is 3 and Maximum error is 10
[image]

Best i could find on plotly.js is this graph
[image]

I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to edit the error lines or there hover labels in plotly to show me Maximum and Minimum values like in the first image any help would be appreciated please i am new to javascript and this so please bear with me

Thanks

Comment: You should consider adding code examples of what you've tried so far, and links to the references that you include, rather than screenshots.

Comment: If you want to get same graph as in your first example, you would need to draw the error bars yourself by using a scatter plot with labels for the ends and then add the lines.